# Форма регистрации(ошибки, условия)

Tags: форма, регистрация, условия

Здравствуйте. Когда пользователь начинает регистрироваться и делает ошибки(не правильный пароль или занят Email) в форме регистрации, то ему все ошибки(условия регистрации) выдаются сразу. 
Я бы хотел что бы ошибки вылазили по мере исправления предыдущих. Как это сделать?
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: с помощью javascript: ajax-запрос на событие onchange поля email, пароль проверять с помощью регулярных выражений

Comment: Создайте одну функцию, которая будет запускать процесс проверки всех полей, затем вызывайте ее каждый раз при изменении содержимого полей пользователем. Единственное отличие от предыдущего варианта (в котором все ошибки выводятся сразу) - прекращайте проверять следующие поля, как только найдете ошибку. Ответ не пишу, потому что не знаю, о каких технологиях идет речь и на каких языках нужно решить задачу.